# Internet stops working if proxy settings are removed from browser

Tags: networking, proxy

I am puzzled as I cant find this solutions or even the name of the process. I used to work in an organization where there administrator had ISA server setup to use proxy in such a way that the internet would stop working if the proxy is removed from the browser. I want to do the same thing... Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is probably blocked in the firewall in the router

Comment: Even if we block port 80 and 443 in the router and use proxy on host's browser side... we still won't get access to internet.